# Why is it possible redefine functions with different numbers of arguments than its prototype in a different file?

Tags: c, linkage, function-prototypes

I have 2 files - main.c and main1.c.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(void)
{
}

int main(void)
{
    foo();
}
```

main1.c:

```
void foo(int a, int b);
```

I compile using gcc:

gcc main.c main1.c -o main

Compilation gives no errors. Why is this possible if functions prototypes have external linkage by default? Shouldn't gcc give me an error that foo is redefined with different number of arguments? Where is C standard is this behavior described?

Comment: Is `void foo(int a, int b);` implemented?

Comment: No, there is only a prototype for this function in main.1

Comment: So, there you have it (see @Ting's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's because your `void foo(int a, int b);` in main1.c is only a forward **declaration**. Nothing is defined yet.
If you change your main1.c to:

```
void foo(int a, int b) {}
```

you will see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading about [translation units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

The thing is, each source file is compiled separately, the compiler knows nothing of other source files, only things it sees in the current source file. It's not until the *linker* sees multiple definitions that you will get errors.

In your `main1.c` file, you may even *call* the `foo` function with two arguments (or the compiler would complain), but it might lead to *undefined behavior* in the actual definition of the function, as the number of arguments it expects differ from the ones in the actual call. In your case it might not be so bad, as the actual function doesn't have arguments. But think if it was the opposite, the actual function takes two argument, and you call it from another translation unit with no arguments, what would the value of those arguments in the actual function be?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the linker (which will link your object files together) does not distinguish what arguments that function accepts.

\And since `void foo(int a, int b);` does not create a new symbol, but only notifies the compiler of such a symbol's existence it won't complain eighteen.

if you attempt to create the function twice though

```
void foo(int a, int b) {}
```

Now this will issue a linker error saying that the symbol `foo` is defined twice.